# Termination condition $(\alpha + x - \beta(1+x^2))g'(x)+(1+x^2)g''(x)+Eg(x)=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

I am trying to find values for $E$ for which I obtain polynomial solutions for the differential equation

$$(\alpha + x - \beta(1+x^2))g'(x)+(1+x^2)g''(x)+Eg(x)=0$$

I assume to have solutions of the form

$$g(x)=x^{\gamma_j}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n,\gamma_j} x^n$$ where $j={1, 2}$ and $\gamma_1 =1, \gamma_2=0$. I have first tried to look at the case $j=1$ and by differentiating $g(x)$ and plug it in I get (omit $\gamma_j$ index)
$$\frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}a_{0}=a_1$$
and for $n>0$
$$ (\alpha - \beta)a_n (n+1) + a_{n+1} (n+1)(n+2) + a_{n-1} (E + n^2) - \beta a_{n-2} (n-1)=0$$
at this point I am stuck...I dont know how to proceed to find out the value for $E$ for which the recurrence relation terminates. I would already be satisfied to find the value for the first few $n={1, 2, 3}$. Do I need to take also the second solution in consideration? What am I missing? Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: What are your initial conditions or boundary conditions? There is no singularity at $x=0$, why are you using a Frobenius power series? The power series will have a radius of convergence of 1, any truncated series is only useful for small $x$. This might restrict the usefulness of such a solution.

Comment: I do not have certain initial conditions. For $g(0)=g_0$ and $g'(0)=g_1$ I want to find polynomial solutions.
Why Frobenius, well because $x<1$ is enough for me, if I find a value for $E=E_N$ such that $a_{n+1} = 0$ for $ n>N$ than the solution I get is a polynomial solution which should be defined on $x<1$. I don't truncate the series by cutting terms for $x \ll 1$.

Comment: I don't see how the polynomial solution is possible. If $g$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, the $\beta x^2 g'(x)$  has a term of degree $n+1$, which cannot be countered by anything else.